# mock python class method

Tags: python, mocking, python-mock

I have been trying to mock a class method, but so far i have not been successfull and not able to find proper documentation, can any of you show how i can write mock test for the below code

### one.py:

```
class abc:
    def classmethod:
        return "message from class methos"
```

### two.py:

```
from one.py import abc
client = abc()

def function:
    res = abc.classmethos()  # how to mock so abc.classmethod() returns "hello" instead of "message from class method"
    return res
```

Comment: This is invalid Python syntax.

Comment: I am new to python and  Mock and hence error. But idea is to mock a instance method

Comment: I guess you would have to fix your Python first.